# Key scrambler for Open Office

Tags: windows, open-source, security

I'm looking for a software that will scramble my key strokes when using Open Office.

This is a basic security measure I deploy on all browsers of my business computer due to previous exploits I've encountered on my computer. Ultimately, I'm protecting myself against key-loggers and similar spy-ware that might go undetected in spite of the variety of anti-virus/malware/spyware programs I already rely on.

I'd like to be able to achieve the same key scrambling mechanism for Open Office, particularly for the word processing and spreadsheet programs.

Do any free plugins/add-ons exist?

Alternatively, does there exist any free system-wide solutions that will oversee my entire operating system (Windows)?